# JSON Schema - matching based on array inclusion

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following simple JSON schema that does the regular expression match based on the content field of my data:

```
{  
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "allOf":[  
       {  
          "properties":{  
           "content":{  
                "pattern":"some_regex"
             }
          }
       }
}
```

It successfully matches the following data:

```
{
    "content": "some_regex"
}
```

Now lets say I want to add a list of UUIDs to ignore to my data:

```
{
   "content": "some_regex",
   "ignoreIds" ["123", "456"]
}
```

The problem arises when I want to modify my schema not to match when a given value is present in the list of *ignoreIds*:

Here is my failed attempt:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "allOf": [{
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "pattern": "some_regex"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "properties": {
      "ignoreIds": {
        "not": {
          // how do I say 'do not match if "123" is in the ignoreIds array'????
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your JSON schema for the ignoreIds has to be:

```
"ignoreIds": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": { 
        "type": "integer", 
        "not": { 
            "enum": [131, 132, whatever numbers you want] 
        } 
    }
}
```

which says

> any value in the array ignoreIds matching the not-enum will make the
>   json invalid

This works of course for an array of strings also:

```
"ignoreIds": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": { 
        "type": "string", 
        "not": { 
            "enum": ["131", "132"] 
        } 
    }
}
```

Tested with [JSON Schema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#)